# How do I iterate over return type of Either<ClientError, List<Employee>>?

Tags: java, kotlin

Lets say my function A is returning Either<ClientError, List>.
I assign it to a variable lets say:
val employeeList = A().
for (e in employeeList) gives me an error saying "for loop must have iterator". How do I overcome this?

Comment: `Either` has a left and right part. Just use `employeeList.right()`.

Comment: Are you using Arrow's `Either`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using either, but you can try using a when statement to cast the result to you appropriate type.

Something like this

```
when(val result = myFunction()){
            is ClientError -> {  //your code}
            is List<> -> { //your code}
            else -> {//..}
}
```

**The best approach** would be to make another sealed class, that contains your two type that you want to return.

```
sealed class MySealedClass{
data class Success(val data: List<Employee>) : MySealedClass()
data class Failed(val error: ClientError) : MySealedClass()
}
```

then, return this type from your function

```
fun myFunction(): MySealedClass{
 return if() MySealedClass.Failed(ClientError()) else MySealedClass.Success(resultList)
}
```

And use the same approach with when, but this time without an else branch

```
when(val result = myFunction()){
                is MySealedClass.Failed -> {  //your code}
                is MySealedClass.Success -> { //your code}
    }
```